# Exercise with fundamental theorem of calculus and change of variables

Tags: calculus

Any ideas for proving that with a change of variables $\int_{0}^{a}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{a}f\left(a-x\right)dx$?

Comment: I could say that I have two, but I would be lying.

Comment: What's wrong with $u=a-x?$

Comment: @saulspatz it doesn't get a minus out of this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarifying what @saulspatz said,

Using $u = a-x$ substitution turns $\displaystyle \int_0^a f(x)\,dx$ into $\displaystyle\int_a^0 -f(a-x)\,dx$.

However, $\displaystyle\int_a^0 -f(a-x)\,dx = \int_0^a f(a-x)\,dx $.

Comment: What I didn't consider was the change in the limits of integration. Thank you!